# What is the most elegant way to get battery info in background?

Tags: ios, swift

I need my phone to make an audible beep when battery drops below 20%.

I just don't know how to make my code run in the background. I have tried:
 `applicationDidEnterBackground'(application: UIApplication)`

But it only checks the battery once when the app goes into background; it does not update.

I know how to access battery charge. This is what I have:

```
var power = Float()
func batteryLevel() {  
    power = UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryLevel
    if power < 0.2 { 
        println("Beep")
    }
}
```

How can I make this run regularly in the background? Are there a bunch of hoops to jump through?

Comment: It’s unlikely your app will ever pass Apple’s review if you do this...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still a relatively new developer. Why is this?

Comment: Because your app would somehow try monitor the system. Something Apple does not want apps to do. But this is just me, probably Apple feels different in this special case. (If Apple left a way to achieve that at all.)

Comment: In my opinion, apple should approve that, because it's a public property without any hacks needed to get the info.

Comment: Check this system [notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification), but I think it's going to be really hard to keep you app monitoring the battery while on background, there are only a few types of application that can use background processing and you need to be one of them to be approved. Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) it might help you

Answer (score 0):

You could check every x minutes by using the NSTimer:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: Selector("checkBattery"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

That timer calls the `checkBattery` method after 10 minutes and waits for another 10 minutes.

Comment: Would this go in applicationDidEnterBackground'(application: UIApplication) ?

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly fine

Comment: This only works when I bring the app back into the foreground, for some reason. It gives me all of the beeps that I should have gotten from the background very quickly after the app has been re-opened.

Comment: NSTimer won't work. You can only run background tasks for a very limited time before the OS kills it.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is/can use any of the background modes available then you can enable `UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification` but this depends on your apps ability to run in a background mode.